# Files are not visible in eclipse luna how can i get?

Tags: java, jsp, project

I am using eclipse luna and my jsp file is not visible in web content,when i tried to make a jsp file with the same name which is hidden then is show the message that file already exist and hidden due to resource filter.
For ex In my project there was already an index.jsp file but it is not visible now ,when i tried to make a new index.jsp file it show an error 
" This file is hidden in the workspace due to resource filters.  To override existing resource filters, a linked file can be created instead."
How can i get my hidden file by Resource filter.[before trouble in web content there was jsp files but now it is not visible

[image]

Comment: enable it or make it visible in the filter settings

Answer (score 0):

You can always choose to hide system files or generated class files in one of the navigation views.

try with  **Project Explorer**, click the **Menu button** to open the drop-down menu of display options.

Select **Customize View**....

or just take a look to the [doc](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-48b.htm)

[image]